# How to send events to Highcharts / Highstock?

Tags: events, customization, highcharts

I'd like the range buttons to be completely out of the chart in plain custom HTML.

Is there an option to send events to Hichstock?

For example, I'd like to send something like: range button (type) 'clicked'.

Comment: Yes, you can* but I don't see a reason to do that. I mean, buttons in `rangeSelector` are changing extremes using `chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max)`. You need to simply calculate new extremes and apply them. *- you can, but it won't work if buttons are disabled.

Comment: @PawełFus it's not about extremes, it's more about UI.  I'd really love to separate the range buttons from the chart, and it's totally fine for me to have them static. It's for 1d 1w 3m 6m etc... the usual stock chart. The problem is I don't see any way to communicate with the chart from outside unless I rebuild it each time.

Comment: I mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tbk3cr11/2/ - no need to rebuild the chart. Of course this is very basic example.

Comment: I think I found it. When I create hc, I can then call for example: $(hc.rangeSelector.buttons[0].element).click()

Comment: @PawełFus your solution makes more sense than mine :D Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you can use internal function: `chart.rangeSelector.clickButton(index, redraw)` - but still, you need to first render buttons on the chart.. (see my first comment and `*- part` ;) )